# Concatenate files based such that only common headers are put together

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, concatenation

I have two CSV files that share similar headers:`sample_scv_1.csv` is::

```
Transaction_date,Product,Payment_Type
1/2/09 6:17,Product1,Mastercard
1/2/09 4:53,Product1,Visa
1/2/09 13:08,Product1,Mastercard
1/3/09 14:44,Product1,Visa
1/4/09 12:56,Product2,Visa
1/4/09 13:19,Product1,Visa
```

Similarly, `sample_scv_2.csv` is ::

```
Transaction_date,Product,Price,Name
1/1/09 11:05,Product1,1200,Janis
1/5/09 4:10,Product1,1200,Nicola
1/6/09 7:18,Product1,1200,asuman
1/2/09 1:11,Product1,1200,Lena
```

Here in these two files Columns/Fields `Transaction_date` and `Product` are common and I want to concatenate these files but it should consider the header information.

```
cat  sample_scv_1.csv  sample_scv_2.csv > combined_scv.csv
```

will concatenate the files but will not consider the header information. I can do so easily for smaller files in `R` as:

```
sample_one <- read.csv("sample_scv_1.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sample_two <- read.csv("sample_scv_2.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

common_headers <-  intersect(colnames(sample_one), colnames(sample_two))

concat.samples <- rbind(sample_one[, common_headers, drop = FALSE], sample_two[, common_headers, drop = FALSE] )

write.csv(concat.samples, "combined_samples.csv")
```

My required output is ::

```
Transaction_date,Product
1/2/09 6:17,Product1
1/2/09 4:53,Product1
1/2/09 13:08,Product1
1/3/09 14:44,Product1
1/4/09 12:56,Product2
1/4/09 13:19,Product1
1/1/09 11:05,Product1
1/5/09 4:10,Product1
1/6/09 7:18,Product1
1/2/09 1:11,Product1
```

Since my files are big 20000 columns and 10000 fields, can this be done efficiently from command-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` command with a `tail -n +2` on 2nd file to remove duplicate header:

```
cut -d, -f1,2 file1.csv <(tail -n +2 file2.csv)
```

---

Based on comments below it seems OP doesn't want to specify common column numbers and wants this script to figure it out based on header row. These header fields can be in different order also.

Here is an awk script with extensive comments to make it work:

```
$> cat cmn.awk

function prnt(hdr) {          # utilitiy function for printing using common header arrays
   for (i=1; i<=length(hdr); i++)
      printf "%s%s", (i>1?OFS:""), $(hdr[i])
   print ""
}
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == 1 {                     # for 1st record of 1st file in list
   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        col[$i] = i           # for 1st file save each col name and col num in array "col"

   getline < ARGV[2]          # read 1st record of 2nd file in list

   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)       # for 1st record of 2nd file in list
      if ($i in col) {        # if this field exists in array "col"    
         hdr1[++k] = col[$i]  # save common col num of 1st file in array "hdr1"    
         hdr2[k] = i          # save common col num of 2nd file in array "hdr2"
         # print header row
         printf "%s%s", (k>1?OFS:""), $i
      }

   close(ARGV[2])
   if (k) print ""

}
FNR == 1 {
   next                        # skip first record from both files
}
FNR == NR {
   prnt(hdr1)                  # print records from first file
   next
}
{
   prnt(hdr2)                  # print records from second file
}
```

Now use it as:

```
$> awk -f cmn.awk file1.csv file2.csv

Transaction_date,Product
1/2/09 6:17,Product1
1/2/09 4:53,Product1
1/2/09 13:08,Product1
1/3/09 14:44,Product1
1/4/09 12:56,Product2
1/4/09 13:19,Product1
1/1/09 11:05,Product1
1/5/09 4:10,Product1
1/6/09 7:18,Product1
1/2/09 1:11,Product1
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well for the sample data but as I have mentioned in my last lines; my data is very high dimensional, is there a way to circumvent explicit typing of the columns?

Comment: Here you have set `cut`  to list fields `1` and `2`. It will be difficult to do that in a data that has 10000 fields. In other words: how would you identify common fields from two very very large files to give a parameter to cut.

Comment: How do you think common fields should be identified? Is it based on header?

Comment: Yes! The titles based on the header. Here `Transaction_date` and `Product` are common.

Comment: Is the order of fields same in both CSV files or it can vary too?

Comment: The order of fields is normally the same but I would like to cater for a case when it can vary.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; print "Transaction_date,Product" } NR==FNR && NR>1 {print $1,$2}  NR!=FNR && FNR>1 {print $1,$2}' file1 file2
Transaction_date,Product
1/2/09 6:17,Product1
1/2/09 4:53,Product1
1/2/09 13:08,Product1
1/3/09 14:44,Product1
1/4/09 12:56,Product2
1/4/09 13:19,Product1
1/1/09 11:05,Product1
1/5/09 4:10,Product1
1/6/09 7:18,Product1
1/2/09 1:11,Product1
```

Explanation:

`BEGIN{}`: This is used to make `awk` aware of that fields are separated by `,`  and print the header message.
`NR==FNR` : Means  first file's contents and `NR>1` means skip the header of file1.
`NF!=FNR` : Means content of files other then first file and `NR>1` means , skip the header of file2.
`{print $1,$2}` : Print column1 and colum2 of file1 and file2 ,which are separated by `,`.

Comment: Thanks! This works well for the sample data but as I have mentioned in my last lines; my data is very high dimensional, is there a way to circumvent explicit typing of the columns?

Comment: do you have range of columns ? like from `1-20` or `20-30` or `2-last` . If you do have then its achievable easily using `for loop`

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I think like I did with R, first task would be to identify the common headers.

Comment: General stuff:  `$0` will print whole columns. 

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) `: This will also print whole columns.

`for(i=1;i<=5;i++)` : This will print between `1-5` columns

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `awk`:

```
awk -F, '!/^Transaction_date/ || NR==FNR {print $1, $2}' File1 File2

Transaction_date Product
1/2/09 6:17 Product1
1/2/09 4:53 Product1
1/2/09 13:08 Product1
1/3/09 14:44 Product1
1/4/09 12:56 Product2
1/4/09 13:19 Product1
1/1/09 11:05 Product1
1/5/09 4:10 Product1
1/6/09 7:18 Product1
1/2/09 1:11 Product1
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well for the sample data but as I have mentioned in my last lines; my data is very high dimensional, is there a way to circumvent explicit typing of the columns?